# Dictionary keys are being converted when transposed in a Cell Validation list

Tags: vba, validation, date, dictionary

I'm confronted with a formating problem in a cell data validation.
I'm trying to add two list in cells for the user to select within a range of date.

I have two nearly identical dictionaries which hold the date, their keys are in the "yyyy-mm-dd" format but are strings. I manipulate the dictionaries to remove unnecessary date and keeping only the needed one.

I'm using the following piece of code to transpose the keys in the validation.

```
With .Range("DATE")
    .Validation.Delete
    .Cells(1, 1).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Formula1:=Join(dict_MIN.Keys, ",")
    .Cells(1, 2).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Formula1:=Join(dict_MAX.Keys, ",")
End With
```

It works properly except for one bit. The strings in the keys are then not considered as strings but as dates. Therefore their format in the list change and are displayed as yy/mm/dd which is quite confusing for the users.

Is there any way to join these keys as string so their value are passed as is?

Thanks

Comment: You could re-write the join function to iterate the dictionary and use a format on the keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works fine for me

```
Dim s As String
Dim d As New Scripting.Dictionary

d.Add "2016-12-02", ""
d.Add "2016-12-08", ""
d.Add "2016-12-09", ""

s = Join(d.Keys(), ",")

ActiveCell.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=s
```

here is the custom join to try also

```
Public Function CustomJoin(arr As Variant, strDelim As String) As String

Dim intCounter As Integer

For intCounter = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    CustomJoin = CustomJoin & format(arr(intCounter),"dd/mm/yyyy") & IIf(intCounter < UBound(arr), strDelim, vbNullString)
Next intCounter

End Function
```

Comment: Hi @Nathan_Sav, I tried both of your solution and they didn't work. I believe that it must have to do with my regional setting.

[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VDipI.jpg

Comment: try in the immediate pane ? dateserial(2016,12,1) see if it's 1/12/2016 or 12/1/2016  there's a way to flip these also

Comment: It returns
?dateserial(2016,12,1)
2016-12-01

Comment: looks like you're using a yyyy-mm-dd format, there's a few articles here and on Mr Excel on how to reverse them

Comment: I had to resort to copying the keys on a range and using this range as source for my validation.